# Using javascript to download file as a.csv file

Tags: javascript, csv

I am trying to export a file as .csv file so that when the user clicks on the download button, the browser would automatically download the file as .csv.
I also want to be able to set a name for the .csv file to be exported

I am using javascript to do this

The code is below:

```
function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
  var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
  var str = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var line = '';
    for (var index in array[i]) {
      if (line != '') line += ','

      line += array[i][index];
    }

    str += line + '\r\n';
  }

  return str;
}

// Example
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Create Object
  var items = [
    { "name": "Item 1", "color": "Green", "size": "X-Large" },
    { "name": "Item 2", "color": "Green", "size": "X-Large" },
    { "name": "Item 3", "color": "Green", "size": "X-Large" }];

  // Convert Object to JSON
  var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);

  // Display JSON
  $('#json').text(jsonObject);

  // Convert JSON to CSV & Display CSV
  $('#csv').text(ConvertToCSV(jsonObject));

  $("#download").click(function() {
    alert("2");
    var csv = ConvertToCSV(jsonObject);
    window.open("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(csv))
    ///////

  });

});
```

Comment: did you happen to get this working?

Answer (score 44):

I have written a solution in this thread: [How to set a file name using window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034754/how-to-set-a-file-name-using-window-open/24643984#24643984)

This is the simple solution:

```
$("#download_1").click(function() {
    var json_pre = '[{"Id":1,"UserName":"Sam Smith"},{"Id":2,"UserName":"Fred Frankly"},{"Id":1,"UserName":"Zachary Zupers"}]';
    var json = $.parseJSON(json_pre);

    var csv = JSON2CSV(json);
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", csv]);
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.href = url;
    downloadLink.download = "data.csv";

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
});
```

JSON2CSV function:

```
function JSON2CSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';
    var line = '';

    if ($("#labels").is(':checked')) {
        var head = array[0];
        if ($("#quote").is(':checked')) {
            for (var index in array[0]) {
                var value = index + "";
                line += '"' + value.replace(/"/g, '""') + '",';
            }
        } else {
            for (var index in array[0]) {
                line += index + ',';
            }
        }

        line = line.slice(0, -1);
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';

        if ($("#quote").is(':checked')) {
            for (var index in array[i]) {
                var value = array[i][index] + "";
                line += '"' + value.replace(/"/g, '""') + '",';
            }
        } else {
            for (var index in array[i]) {
                line += array[i][index] + ',';
            }
        }

        line = line.slice(0, -1);
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: where do you get JSON2CSV(json) that libreary from

Comment: Thanks @Jewel this is helpful...I saved a JS fiddle including a header row of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/m788fu63/1/

Answer (score 42):

in modern browsers there is a new attribute in anchors.

`download`

http://caniuse.com/download

so instead of using

```
window.open("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(csv))
```

create a download link:

```
<a href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,'+escape(csv)+'" download="filename.csv">download</a>
```

another solution is to use php

**EDIT**

i don't use jQuery, but you need to edit your code to add the download link
with something like that in your function.

```
var csv=ConvertToCSV(jsonObject),
a=document.createElement('a');
a.textContent='download';
a.download="myFileName.csv";
a.href='data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,'+escape(csv);
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: Hi But I can't download the content I want is there more codes I need to edit

Comment: what you mean ? use onefo the supporting browsers (chrome for example).with javascript dynamically insert the href data and the download filename.

Comment: '+escape(csv)+' 
this is what I see in the excel file

Comment: Because you might have copied the html to the page. He is suggesting you "create" the csv link using javascript, thus '+escape(csv)+' is going to break out of the single quoted string of html and insert the escaped csv in the href link.

Answer (score 15):

Try these Examples:

Example 1:

```
JsonArray = [{
    "AccountNumber": "1234",
    "AccountName": "abc",
    "port": "All",
    "source": "sg-a78c04f8"

}, {
    "Account Number": "1234",
    "Account Name": "abc",
    "port": 22,
    "source": "0.0.0.0/0",
}]

JsonFields = ["Account Number","Account Name","port","source"]

function JsonToCSV(){
    var csvStr = JsonFields.join(",") + "\n";

    JsonArray.forEach(element => {
        AccountNumber = element.AccountNumber;
        AccountName   = element.AccountName;
        port          = element.port
        source        = element.source

        csvStr += AccountNumber + ',' + AccountName + ','  + port + ',' + source + "\n";
        })
        return csvStr;
}
```

You can download the csv file using the following code :

```
function downloadCSV(csvStr) {

    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csvStr);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'output.csv';
    hiddenElement.click();
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how to modify the "downloadCSV" function so it supports spanish characters?

Comment: Any idea on how to do this with an excel file?

Answer (score 8):

I just wanted to add some code here for people in the future since I was trying to export JSON to a CSV document and download it.

I use `$.getJSON` to pull json data from an external page, but if you have a basic array, you can just use that.

This uses [Christian Landgren's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31536517/1274820) code to create the csv data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var JSONData = $.getJSON("GetJsonData.php", function(data) {
        var items = data;
        const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value; // specify how you want to handle null values here
        const header = Object.keys(items[0]);
        let csv = items.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','));
        csv.unshift(header.join(','));
        csv = csv.join('\r\n');

        //Download the file as CSV
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", csv]);
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        downloadLink.href = url;
        downloadLink.download = "DataDump.csv";  //Name the file here
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    });
});
```

Edit: It's worth noting that `JSON.stringify` will escape quotes in quotes by adding `\"`. If you view the CSV in excel, it doesn't like that as an escape character.

You can add `.replace(/\\"/g, '""')` to the end of `JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)` to display this properly in excel (this will replace `\"` with `""` which is what excel prefers).

Full Line: `JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer).replace(/\\"/g, '""')`

Answer (score 7):

One-liner function for simple JSON with static titles

Assuming arr is JSON array, you can also replace the first string with comma separated titles end with `\n`

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (`${acc}${Object.values(curr).join(",")}\n`), "")
```

Or with the window.open function mentioned before

```
window.open(`data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (`${acc}${Object.values(curr).join(",")}\n`), "")}`)
```

You should also consider `escape` the strings or replace the `,` to avoid extra cells

Answer (score 0):

If your data comes from a SQL Database, all your lines should have the same structure, but if coming from a NoSQL Database you could have trouble using standard answers. I elaborated on above JSON2CSV for such a scenario.
Json data example

```
  [ {"meal":2387,"food":"beaf"},
    {"meal":2387,"food":"apple","peeled":"yes", "speed":"fast" },
    {"meal":2387,"food":"pear", "speed":"slow", "peeled":"yes" } ]
```

Answer

```
"meal","food","peeled","speed"
"2387","beaf","",""
"2387","apple","yes","fast"
"2387","pear","yes","slow"
```

Code for headers and double quotes for simplicity.

```
function JSON2CSV(objArray) {
  var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

  var str = '';
  var line = '';

  // get all distinct keys      
  let titles = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let obj = array[i];
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key,value])=>{
      //console.log('key=', key, "   val=", value );
      if (titles.includes(key) ) {
        // console.log (key , 'exists');
        null;
      }
      else {
        titles.push(key);
      }
    })
  }
  let htext =  '"' + titles.join('","') + '"';
  console.log('header:', htext);
  // add to str
  str += htext + '\r\n';
  //
  // lines
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var line = '';
    // get values by header order
    for (var j = 0; j < titles.length; j++) {
      // match keys with current header
      let obj = array[i];
      let keyfound = 0;    
      // each key/value pair
      Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key,value])=>{
        if (key == titles[j]) {
          // console.log('equal tit=', titles[j] , ' e key ', key ); // matched key with header
          line += ',"' + value +  '"';
          keyfound = 1; 
          return false;
        }

      })
      if (keyfound == 0) {
        line += ',"'  +  '"';   // add null value for this key
      } // end loop of header values

    }

    str += line.slice(1) + '\r\n';
  }
  return str;
}
```