# How do I use a context from a loaded view to export a csv file in django?

Tags: python, django

I have written a Django app that does a database query and displays the data in a table.  I want to create a link at the bottom of the page that allows the user to export this data to a csv file.  So basically I want to take the query object from the original view and pass that to the csv export view.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**(Assuming you need to download the same table's data into csv file) You can do this without another server call with javascript:**

As reference you can see: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564103/using-javascript-to-download-file-as-a-csv-file)