# How to save CSV file from API response using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

In my application I need to save on my computer a CSV file which comes from an API response. The function which sends POST request is (I am using Redux):

```
export const postCsv = sensorData => (dispatch, getState) => {

  const token = getState().auth.token;

  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': "application/json"
    }
  }

  // If token exists, add to headers config
  if (token) {
    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Token ${token}`
  }

  // Post request to API
  axios.post(`${baseURL}/sensors_data/csv`, sensorData, config)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      dispatch({
        type: POST_CSV,
        payload: res.data
      })
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response);
  })
}
```

and response from API is:

[image]

I execute the postCsv function after a button click. As you can see, the response code is 200 and every data has been sent correctly. I just don't know what should I do to download and save the file. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17564369/2622292

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by [@cocco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2450730/cocco) in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17564369/2622292), you could dynamically generate an anchor with the **[`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download)** attribute.

**NOTE:** For the sake of simplicity, I'll demo getting the data part form an API using a `useEffect` and a fake `HttpClient` service that has a static `get` method that returns the data. But hope you get the general idea.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import HttpClient from "./HttpClient";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const [dataInCSV, setDataInCSV] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    HttpClient.get().then(res => setDataInCSV(res));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {dataInCSV && (
        <a
          href={`data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${escape(dataInCSV)}`}
          download="filename.csv"
        >
          download
        </a>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Here's a **[Working Sample Code Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-download-csv-from-api-response?file=src/App.js)** for your ref.

Answer (score 14):

```
const downloadFile = () => {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data])) 
      const link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = url
      link.setAttribute('download', "yourfilename.csv")
      document.body.appendChild(link)
      link.click()
      link.remove()
  }
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer has no votes, it worked fine for me. Thanks @HogasAndreiMarius